# TextMate match a block of code

Tags: regex, textmate, atom-editor

guys.
I am working on a syntax theme to Atom text editor. I need to match a block of code.
 
For example,

> for {
>       // some code 
>   }

```
I can do this by using
"begin": "(for){"
"end": "}"
"patterns": [//some patterns]
```

The problem is that inside this for loop I can have another block of code (e.g. if {}) and the bracket in "if" will match as the end of "for" block.
Is there any workaround? Because I need to use specific patterns only inside this block.

Comment: [here maybe](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=regex+matching+brace)

Answer (score 1):

There is some workaround:

Assuming, there won't be nested blocks inside of the for loop, you can use the following pattern (I don't know anything about the regex engine you are using, but that pattern should work with most) :

```
'\{[^{}]*)([^{}]{[^{}]*})*?[^{}]*YOURPATTERNS([^{}]{[^{}]*})*+[^{}]*+\}'
```

Let's unpack it: 
   It starts with an opening bracket and continues with as many non-bracket characters as possible. Then, as many opening bracket + stuff + closing bracket pairs as needed can follow. Afterwards, the patterns you want to match within the loop can come. Then the rest of possible pairs of opening and closing brackets follow. Then the rest of non-bracket characters will come to enclose the gap to the closing bracket.

**Nested brackets**: 
Since you need nested brackets, you have to use a very strong regex engine that supports recursive patterns. I have written something for that case using the regex module of python (not the re module). The following works there, if you use another engine with recursion you would have to adapt it, otherwise it is fine.

```
r'\{(?P<any>[^{}]*)(?P<pairs>(?P<posany>[^{}]*+)\{(?&pairs)*?(?&posany)\})*?(?&any)YOURPATTERNS(?&pairs)*+(?&posany)\}'
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I have nested blocks, that's a problem

Comment: Nested ones inside of the for loop?

Comment: yees, for example, I can have another for loop or if statement

Comment: another for loop would be fine, but another for loop within that second for loop would cause trouble